# How can my application access the list of files and folders that Windows Explorer displays under "Quick Access"?

Tags: windows, desktop

Windows Explorer (at least in Windows 10) has a section that it calls "Quick Access", which displays a list of frequently used files and folders.

How can my application access this same list?